# How do I extract the Hour/Minute from a datetime object and get rid of the Year/Month/Day/Second section?

Tags: python, datetime

I am writing a program to track my working hours as a chef. I'm looking for it to ask when I started, finished and how long a break I had that day. The problem I am running into is I keep getting a value error on line 12 (`time data '1900-01-01 10:00:00' does not match format '%H:%M'`) and I'm having trouble applying the threads on here that try to explain the solution to my own problem. I know what I need to do is extract some of the data from the datetime object as a whole but so far everything I have tried has thrown up an error.

Code below;

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = "%H:%M"  # The time format i.e hours and minutes

print("Please input your starting and finishing times for the following days.")
print("Wednesday:")  # Denotes which day is being asked about

wed_start_in = (input("What time did you start?")) # asks starting time
wed_start = str(datetime.strptime(wed_start_in, "%H:%M"))  # converts time start input into a datetime object
wed_finish_in = (input("And what time did you finish?"))  # asks finishing time
wed_finish = str(datetime.strptime(wed_start_in, "%H:%M"))
wed_hours = datetime.strptime(wed_start, fmt) - datetime.strptime(wed_finish, fmt)
print(wed_hours)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting back and forth into strings; instead, parse each of the times once, then keep them as times. Only convert them back to strings (if necessary) at the very end.

```
wed_start_in = input("What time did you start?") # asks starting time
wed_start = datetime.strptime(wed_start_in, "%H:%M")  # converts time start input into a datetime object
wed_finish_in = input("And what time did you finish?")  # asks finishing time
wed_finish = datetime.strptime(wed_finish_in, "%H:%M")
wed_hours = wed_finish - wed_start
print(wed_hours)
```

Comment: output is always 0:00:00

Comment: Ah, of course; the code also used `wed_start_in` for both the start and end times. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: So when you suggest to parse each of the times once before keeping them as times, I'm having difficulty working out how to actually parse them. Would dateutil work?

Comment: The way you're already doing with `strptime` works fine. Just don't convert back and forth multiple times.